# Apache RewriteRule on VirtualHosts doesn't work with group capture regex

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, mod-rewrite, rewrite, mod-proxy

I need to create a `RewriteRule` to delegate an URL path like `/tdg/image.jpg?mode=crop&width=300&height=300` to a local proxy.

The proxy needs the given URL be transformed into the following format.

```
http://localhost:8888/unsafe/300x300/smart/tdg/image.jpg
```

I tried first using `ProxyPassMatch` apache directive but I can't retrieve the width and height data from the query string.

```
ProxyRequests On
ProxyPreserveHost On
ProxyPassMatch ^\/(tdg.+\.(?:png|jpeg|jpg|gif))\?mode=crop.+width=(d+)&height=(d+) http://localhost:8888/unsafe/$2x$3/smart/$1
```

I also tried `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^\/(tdg.+\.(?:png|jpeg|jpg|gif))\?mode=crop.+width=(d+)&height=(d+) http://localhost:8888/unsafe/$2x$3/smart/$1
```

And in both cases, the result URL for the proxy is `http://localhost:8888/unsafe/x/smart/$1` where should be `http://localhost:8888/unsafe/300x300/smart/tdg/image.jpg`

I have no clue why I can't fetch the `width` and `height` value from the query string, using `group` regex syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `RewriteRule` directive only matches on the path component, it does not include the query string. Try:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} mode=crop.+width=(\d+)&height=(\d+)
RewriteRule ^\/(tdg.+\.(?:png|jpeg|jpg|gif)) http://localhost:8888/unsafe/%1x%2/smart/$1 [P]
```

Note the difference of the back-reference in the replacement when using `RewriteCond`. In order to use back-references from both places, use %N for those from `RewriteCond` and $N for those in the `RewriteRule`.

Comment: Yeah, I had read about `RewriteCond` but I had undestood that was just for a check condition before the `RewriteRule` be evaluated

Comment: Also, was needed escape the regex group `(\d+)` in `RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} width=(\d+)&height=(\d+)`